# Terraform not detecting the manual changes made in azure portal

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I am managing my azure resources via terraform. But for example i have created a Keyvault manually from the Portal in Resource group XYZ. This Resource group XYZ is managed via terraform only. But still the terraform plan is not able to detect the newly created keyvault which should show up as destroy the keyvault in plan as the code for the keyvault is not there.

Can any one help me

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: If you create/import x resource with terraform, it manages only that x resource. Doesn’t do anything with y resource part of the x resource.

Comment: Apart from importing the y resource is there any way that y resource show up in the terraform plan?

Answer (score 0):

Terraform only responsible for **`destroy`** the resources which has created using terraform apply (ie which present in their **`state file`** ) if you are thiking to destroy the manually created **`keyVault`** using terraform.So it won't be possible. If so it should be write up in your terraform state file then only it could be possible to destroy.

Only You can use the manually created resources using `data` like below.

```
data "azurerm_key_vault" "keyvaultname" {
  
}
```

As per **harshavmb** statement it is corerct. If you create/import x resource with terraform, it manages only that x resource. Doesn’t do anything with y resource part of the x resource.